# Reference a user control by name in code behind (dynamically created)

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a checkbox using the method below:

```
for( i = 1; i<7; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 33; j++)
        {
            CheckBox a = new CheckBox();
            a.Name = "SAT_ID_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
            this.Sat_ID_Grid.Children.Add(a);
            a.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ReadOnlyCheckBox");
            Grid.SetRow(a, i );
            Grid.SetColumn(a, j );
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to reference the checkboxes later using "SAT_ID_X_Y"? I cant seem to find the solution. If not how can I reference them? I need to change the .ischecked state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just store the references to the controls somewhere instead of their names, e.g. in a `List<CheckBox>`, then you can access them by index.

Also you actually should not do any of that, use [data-templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and [data-binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to create controls for data. If done right you just need to change a boolean on your data and the check-box will be checked/unchecked.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can use data-templating and data-binding to acheive this goal? Thanks

Comment: @user2584960: No. Why do you think i linked to extensive articles which explain the concepts?

Comment: if accessing the controls by index, the OP can pass the index into `this.Sat_ID_Grid.Children` instead of a custom `List<CheckBox>`. I think there is no way to access a control by name if the collection containing it doesn't support access by name. The `Controls` collection in `winforms` does allow access by name but `Children` in `wpf` doesn't, I don't know why it has to be so.

Comment: @KingKing: The grid may contain other controls, in terms of maintaining a secure index-access a dedicated list is probably preferable. Concerning access by name: Control names in WPF are special and usually are only used with the dedicated method [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) which searches the tree of the control. When assigning a name dynamically you also have to register it in a name-scope for that to work though. It's messy and has very few "legitimate" uses, outside of control-authoring you should not need it.

Comment: How do you "register it in a name-scope"?  Is this what youa re talking about? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746609.aspx

Comment: @user2584960: See "Adding Objects to Runtime Object Trees" on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx). (But as i said, don't use names at all, you already have a reference to the control, there is no point i **getting the very same reference** again using a messy string)